# Apps don't work (HTTP 400 Bad Request) in MySites Web App, but do work in main SharePoint Web App

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-addin, my-site

When I try to add an app to a MySite site collection it looks like it is created without error, but when I try to go to it, it gives me a 400 bad request error.

Apps work fine on our regular sharepoint web app.

I am using the same App Management Service on both web apps.

Notes:
Mysite web app is "http://mysites.mydomain.com:16750"
Main SharePoint web app is "https://portal.mydomain.com"

App domain is "portalapps.mydomain.com"
App prefix is "app"

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your mysite is not using ssl, while your main site is. You're going to have an issue redirecting from the my site (no ssl) to the app web (ssl). So, configure Mysite for ssl, and set the ssl site as the default in AAM.

Comment: That worked.  Thanks much!  We had figured that since we were going from a less secure to more secure it should work.  Lesson learned :)